How to scrape YouTube Thumbnail AB test images?
I'm checking how to approach scraping of the YouTube video thumbnail AB tests.
I see that for some videos where the AB thumbnail test is not active the URL may look like this:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PWirijQkH4M/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNACELwBSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLBKdc7hUQ5L2mS8kOfFpmPfex5Ukw
Meantime, for the videos where the AB thumbnail test is active, the URL looks like this:
https://i9.ytimg.com/vi/PWirijQkH4M/hq720_custom_1.jpg?sqp=CNCcxbQG-oaymwE2CNAFEJQDSFXyq4qpAygIARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBvABAfgB_gmAAtAFigIMCAAQARh_ICgoEzAP&rs=AOn4CLCE9jpzpLAvr53v8BPXtWuD4zYfnQ
So there is something about this part of the URL hqdefault.jpg VS hq720_custom_1.jpg, but I can not find the system in that

Are you using Python - by any chance? How did you get those sample URLs in the first place?

@MauricioAriasOlave for this solution I can use Python as well. The IDs are provided by 3rd party

Not sure if those special thumbnails are embed on the source code of the webpage, but, this scraper seems to get the hq720_custom_1.jpg link. I also think that not every single video has all types of thumbails. As alternative, you could use: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/frame0.jpg - example: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PWirijQkH4M/frame0.jpg and https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PWirijQkH4M/hqdefault.jpg = see the difference.

Unfortunately this does not work :(
